# Extension to n-dimension of the Taylor expansion formula $f(x+ \varepsilon) = e^{\varepsilon \frac{d}{dx}}f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

I've come across this compact way to write the Taylor expansion formula:

$$ f(x+ \varepsilon) = e^{\varepsilon \frac{d}{dx}}f(x) $$

With $\varepsilon$ a generic increment.
So naturally I wondered if, opportunely modified, this holds in n-dimensions.

I thinked to the formula:

$$ f(\bar{x}+ \bar{\varepsilon}) = e^{\bar{\varepsilon} \cdot \bar{\nabla}}f(\bar{x}) $$

That upon expansion gives:

$$ f(\bar{x}+ \bar{\varepsilon}) = f(\bar{x}) + \bar{\varepsilon} \cdot \bar{\nabla}f(\bar{x}) + \frac{1}{2} (\bar{\varepsilon} \cdot \bar{\nabla})^2 f(\bar{x}) + \dots $$

(I found this same reasoning in some Physics textbook, namely Solid State Physics of Ashcroft-Mermin.)

My problem is that I found it wrong, when confronted with the real deal:

$$ f(\bar{x}+ \bar{\varepsilon}) = f(\bar{x}) + \bar{\varepsilon}^T\bar{\nabla}f(\bar{x}) + \frac{1}{2}\bar{\varepsilon}^T H[f(\bar{x})] \bar{\varepsilon} + \dots $$

With $H[f(\bar{x})]$ the Hessian evaluated at $f(\bar{x})$.
Specifically I'm convinced that:

$$ \bar{\varepsilon}^T H[f(\bar{x})] \bar{\varepsilon} \neq  (\bar{\varepsilon} \cdot \bar{\nabla})^2 $$

The question is: I'm I right or wrong ? Thanks for your attention

Moreover, is it possible, if the formula doesn't hold, to find an extremely compact way to express it, as the 1 dimensional case ?

Comment: are they not identical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$\varepsilon^TH[f]\varepsilon = \sum\limits_{j,k = 1}^n \varepsilon_jH[f]_{j,k}\varepsilon_k = \sum\limits_{j,k = 1}^n \varepsilon_j(\partial_j\partial_kf)\varepsilon_k = \sum\limits_{j = 1}^n \varepsilon_j\partial_j\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n \varepsilon_k\partial_kf = (\varepsilon \cdot \nabla)(\varepsilon \cdot \nabla)f,$$
so they are really the same.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I had a wrong interpretation for $(\varepsilon \cdot \nabla)^2$, beacause I thinked that : $$ (\varepsilon \cdot \nabla)^2 = \varepsilon_x^2\partial_{xx} + \varepsilon_y^2\partial_{yy} + \varepsilon_z^2\partial_{zz} + 2 \varepsilon_x\varepsilon_y\partial_{xy} + \dots $$ which is clearly not the case, as I understood

Comment: Do you think that then the general formula holds it ?

Comment: @NunzioDamino Yes, you can prove it by induction (with $e_j$ the standard basis vectors of $\mathbb{R}^n$): $f(x + \varepsilon) = f\left(x + \sum\limits_{j = 1}^n \varepsilon_je_j\right) = \prod\limits_{j = 1}^n e^{\varepsilon_j\partial_j}f(x) = e^{\varepsilon \cdot \nabla}f(x)$.

Comment: perfect, thanks !